# My eslint keeps on giving me react is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am currently using eslint in my project with typescript and react and I am trying to get it work but I dont think I am able to get the configuration quite correct as I am getting errors like 'React' is defined but never used
JSX is being used in the files where this is mentioned
and  it does not fix  when I run eslint fix  my eslint rc is found below and the script that I run too is below

```
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'react-hooks', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 0,
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {},
    },
    'react': {
      createClass: 'createReactClass', // Regex for Component Factory to use,
                                         // default to 'createReactClass'
      pragma: 'React',  // Pragma to use, default to 'React'
      fragment: 'Fragment',  // Fragment to use (may be a property of <pragma>), default to 'Fragment'
      version: 'detect', // React version. 'detect' automatically picks the version you have installed.
                           // You can also use `16.0`, `16.3`, etc, if you want to override the detected value.
                           // It will default to 'latest' and warn if missing, and to 'detect' in the future
    },
    propWrapperFunctions: [
        // The names of any function used to wrap propTypes, e.g. `forbidExtraProps`. If this isn't set, any propTypes wrapped in a function will be skipped.
        'forbidExtraProps',
        {property: 'freeze', 'object': 'Object'},
        {property: 'myFavoriteWrapper'},
        // for rules that check exact prop wrappers
        {property: 'forbidExtraProps', 'exact': true}
    ],
    'componentWrapperFunctions': [
        // The name of any function used to wrap components, e.g. Mobx `observer` function. If this isn't set, components wrapped by these functions will be skipped.
        'observer', // `property`
        {property: 'styled'}, // `object` is optional
        {property: 'observer', 'object': 'Mobx'},
        {property: 'observer', 'object': '<pragma>'} // sets `object` to whatever value `settings.react.pragma` is set to
    ],
    formComponents: [
      // Components used as alternatives to <form> for forms, eg. <Form endpoint={ url } />
      'CustomForm',
      {name: 'Form', 'formAttribute': 'endpoint'}
    ],
    linkComponents: [
      // Components used as alternatives to <a> for linking, eg. <Link to={ url } />
      'Hyperlink',
      {name: 'Link', 'linkAttribute': 'to'}
    ]
  }
 };
```

and I keep on getting this error
"'React' is defined but never used                   @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars"
how do I change the  eslintRc so that it  doesnt give me this error.

also when I set up es lint to fix everything with this script

```
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx,json}'"
```

It doesnt  fix anything either how am I meant to fix this to work correctly  so it auto  fixes all auto fixable problems
My project also includes Node.js files and I am getting

```
Require statement not part of import statement.eslint@typescript-esl
int/no-var-requires
```

This error how do I allow for both too

Comment: can you share github repo?

Comment: No I cant is it necessary ?

Comment: yes it is necessary.

Comment: Why and ill share the relevant info?